# Android SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, simplecursoradapter

I'm using a `ListView` a with `SimpleCursorAdapter` like this:

```
    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c,new String[] {providerclass.tablename}, new int[] {R.id.listview1});
```

I'm not sure whether from is correct, what should I put in from?

When I put this it says `URI` not found.

Comment: The Android Developer Site has some nice articles about `ContentProviders`(link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html ). I'm sure those articles will help you set up and use a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Because I don't see "URI" in your code. BTW, that constructor is deprecated: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter(android.content.Context,int,android.database.Cursor,java.lang.String[],int[])

Comment: @Luksprog: I get this, where am i wrong E/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y/com.x.y.Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://com.x.y.provider/tablename 04-29 16:02:40.693: E/AndroidRuntime(614): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://com.x.y.provider/tablename

Comment: @Yusuf X: I get this, where am i wrong E/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.x.y/com.x.y.Activity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://com.x.y.provider/tablename 04-29 16:02:40.693: E/AndroidRuntime(614): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://com.x.y.provider/tablename

Comment: Without the full code of your `ContentProvider` nobody will be able to figure out why your `URI` is rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
String[] from = new String[] { "CUSTOMER" } // assuming your cursor have field "CUSTOMER"
int[] to = { android.R.id.text1 } // because android.R.layout.simple_list_item1 has such field
```

Comment: :Thanks,I figured it out.I get this in stack trace  E/AndroidRuntime(614): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.x.y/com.x.y.Activity}:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI: content://com.x.y.provider/tablename

04-29 16:02:40.693: E/AndroidRuntime(614): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
 Unknown URI: content://com.x.y.provider/tablename